# Show searched value in exception when nothing is found with First()

Tags: c#, linq

When doing `First()` on an `IEnumerable`, the default exception I'm getting is `Sequence contains no matching element` without the searched value. I need to show the searched `Id`, Is there a way to show the `Id` while I'm in the catch block?

```
public static CustomItem FirstCustom(this IEnumerable<CustomItem> source, Func<CustomItem, bool> predicate)
{
    try
    {
        return source.First(predicate);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"I need to show the searched `Id` here. How to do this? {e.Message}");
    }
}

public class CustomItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: dude, FirstOrDefault.. you will get NULL instead of exception and with simple IF you can handle it

Comment: I don't think you have access to an `Id` at that point. You only have the predicate, which may be simply `return false;`

Comment: Can I find out what was searched with FirstOrDefault?

Comment: The caller knows what they searched with. Why do you need to know inside this method?

Comment: Side note: do you really want to have `set` being `public`? `public int Id { get; private set; }` (or at least `protected internal set;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer: you *can't do this*. Since `predicate` can be an *arbitrary* function, e.g.

```
(CustomeItem c) => 1 == 2
```

the `predicate` may not use any `Id` at all. If you want to search for an `Id` and show it up if it's not found:

```
public static CustomItem FirstCustom(this IEnumerable<CustomItem> source, int id) { 
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); // validate public methods' arguments 

  CustomItem result = source.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);

  if (null == result)
    throw new ArgumentException($"Id {id} has not been found!", "id");
  else
    return result;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using using expression :

How about this :

```
 public static CustomItem FirstCustom(this IEnumerable<CustomItem> source, Expression<Func<CustomItem, bool>> predicate)
    {
        BinaryExpression binExpr = null;
        Expression value = null;
        try
        {
            binExpr = predicate.Body as BinaryExpression;
            value = binExpr.Right;
            var func = predicate.Compile();
            return source.First(func);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception($" No result found for {value} {e.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`First()` will throw an exception [if no matching element is found.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx). So when you are in the exception handler, you have no matching elements, and so there will not be any `Id`.